# Corda /upload/attachment using fetch api gets correct response in network but throws error

Tags: fetch, corda

I'm trying to attach a document to my node. I have the following code in React.

```
const url = `http://localhost:10015/upload/attachment`;
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file',file); // from file select
let result = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'post',
  body: formData
});
```

When I view the network logs, it looks like there isn't an issue[image]

And the response is the hash of the attachment.

When I view the logs, I have this error:

[image]

Could anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score -2):

It looks like your browser is blocking the request based on its Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) policy. Try disabling CORS in the browser or making the same request using a tool like Postman and seeing whether the request is a success.

Comment: But is there any other way to disable CORS in server config? I added CORSFilter as @Provider but that is not working.